# What is a user category exactly?

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

I wanted to add a tab to the user edit page ie `user/%/edit/foo`, and was using the twitter module as a model. After *much* spelunking and stepping through with a debugger, I realised that I needed to add a `hook_user` function in my module so that the `%user_category` part of the menu router path would work.

It's now functioning as expected, but I don't really have a solid idea of what I just did, and haven't found a good explanation anywhere.

Can anyone explain to me what it's about?

Answer (score 1):

user_category_loads fails if given a category that does not exist, which happens at user/uid/edit/not_a_category, and it passes that category for access checks to user/uid/edit/is_a_category and thus access to those is set to false, so bam, wonky menu :'(.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `%user_category` it means that [`user_category_load`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/user_category_load/6) function is called with that argument (the uid).

The function is defined in the user module. These functions serve as a validation, if False it return FALSE, it will result in a 404, but if it return something else, like a user object, that will be passed to whatever callback function / form is run for that url.

In your case, you could probably have used `%user` instead which would have called [user_load](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/user_load/6) which is more simple, and you wouldn't have needed to do all the extra stuff to make `user_category_load` pass.

#### Summary

So `user_category_load` does two things.

1. Check that the category exist so you just can't do user/%/edit/foo.
2. Caches the user object.

Comment: Can you explain the problem that user_category_load solves? When _can't_ I just use %user?

Comment: I guess I still don't quite see _why_ it does #1. Or, for that matter, what as user_category is.
If I set up a menu item at something like `user/%/edit/foo`, why would I want/need to go through this extra hoop? What does it do that user_load by itself doesn't do?

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error, I was able to get a page working as a child of the `user/%/edit` path using code like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Implementation of hook_menu().
 */
function noc_profile_privacy_menu() {
  return array(
    'user/%user_category/edit/privacy' => array(
      'title' => 'Portfolio privacy',
      'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
      'page arguments' => array('noc_profile_privacy_form', 1),
      'access callback' => 'content_profile_page_access',
      'access arguments' => array('profile', 1),
      'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
      'load arguments' => array('%map', '%index'),
    ),
  );
}

/**
 * Implementation of hook_user().
 */
function noc_profile_privacy_user($op, &$edit, &$account, $category = NULL) {
  if ($op === 'categories') {
    return array(array(
      'name' => 'privacy',
      'title' => t('Profile privacy'),
      'weight' => 0,
    ));
  }
}
```

Note that the `'name'` key of what I'm returning in hook_user() is the same as what comes after `user/%user/category/edit` in my hook_menu() definition. I believe that is key. You will also get an error if you omit the `'load arguments'` item, with exactly that value.

So I believe what the user category is is the `'privacy'` in my case - the bit after `edit` in the path of the menu item definition.

Is this an unnecessary complication? Yes, so it seems.

Edit: I see my co-worker hefox beat me to replying to this question. I wouldn't have been able to figure all of this out without Fox's help, so mad props to the Fox.